# Can I have a div tag inside of the head element in a HTML document?

Tags: html

Just want to know if it's possible to have a div tag inside the head element?

Comment: Whether or not an element is a valid child of another can be checked in the specs. For the `head` element the only valid children are [`[...]zero or more elements of metadata content, of which no more than one is a title element and no more than one is a base element[...]`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element)

Comment: Does that mean I can have a div tag in the head tag?

Comment: You mean `head` not `header`. `header` is a different tag.

Comment: I mean the head tag. Can I have a div tag inside the head tag?

Comment: Just like the code I have right above

Comment: I think a bigger question is why in the world would you want to?

Comment: thats why I was asking if its right, because I wasn't sure. So is my code above wrong then?

Comment: your code above is invalid HTML. To translate the specification excerpt provided by @t.niese into English: "The `head` element should only have at least zero elements with metadata (e.g. not data that should be displayed directly on the screen), and there should be no more than one `title` element as a child of the `head` element". `<div>` is not a metadata element, since it has data that should be displayed on the screen, so it's not a valid child of `head`

Comment: Look [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.4.1) for the official documentation. As @Vohuman said, it's invalid. The <head> tag is ONLY for describing the document.

Comment: one more quick question? Can I use single quotes instead of double quotes for my divs as its shown in the code above? what is the difference between using single and double quotes for divs?

Comment: I have updated my question to only one which is if it's possible to have a div in head element in the html, and I got the right answer already. Thank you all

Comment: I think this is a relevant question...and to know why also. In my case I want to create a progress bar that I want it to be one of the first thing to load, and this can be a reason why its interesting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, `<div>` is not a valid tag to be inside of the `<head>` tag, since the `<head>` tag is only meant to be for metadata (such as title and page description), scripts, styles, and other stuff which isn't meant to be displayed. Although putting it in the `<head>` works, it's horrible to do so, and you shouldn't put it there (and the specification says that doing that is not valid HTML. Thanks @t.niese); it's invalid HTML

Also, there is no difference between using `"` or `'` for attribute values (such as `id` in your case), it's just what you prefer. And yes, using `'` is completely valid. I like doing that, since I don't have to hold shift, but it's completely up to you.